# PHP table created from a csv, I need to insert a date

Tags: php, date

Ok I have created a PHP script that prints out data from a .csv file.  Everything is good but the header of the Table I want to have it say report for: current date.  SO here is what I have?

```
    <?php
    $NOWDATE = `date +%m%d%y`;
    print('<tr align="center"><td colspan="15"><h2>Revenue Report for: $NOWDATE</h2></td></tr>');
    ?>
```

This does not work, so I need to find a way to post this to the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes `"` for the string so the variable gets interpreted.

You don't need to do an external `date` call btw - this will do:

```
$NOWDATE = date("d.m.Y");
```

code:

```
print("<tr align=\"center\"><td colspan=\"15\"><h2>Revenue Report for: $NOWDATE</h2></td></tr>");
```

Comment: ok that is fine.  But on the print line how do I put the variable into that I tried double qoutes, no quotes and single quotes too.  Greatly appreciate your help

Comment: @DoCnTex double quotes should work - `print("....");` you'll have to escape any double quotes in there: `\"`

Comment: tried a few things.  I know it may seem simple and I get the markup.  But here is the line and what I have tried:
print('<tr align="center"><td colspan="15"><h2>Revenue Report for:print("$date");</h2></td></tr>');
print('<tr align="center"><td colspan="15"><h2>Revenue Report for:<?php print("$date");?></h2></td></tr>');

Comment: @DoCnTex You need to use double quotes for the opening *and* the closing quote. Mask all double quotes inside the string by prepending them with a backslash.

Comment: guess I dont get it... I have tried every kind of escaping, formatting I know and it either wont work or it just displays what I put in it.  The variable works but putting a print in side of another print?  I think that is what confuses me

Comment: @DocNText nonono, that's not what I mean. I added a code sample to the answer.

Comment: ok maybe I should open my eyes. huh?  man I feel stupid now... thank you that works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

$now = date('d-m-Y');

Then just add $now to your strings anywhere...

See the php documentation on date() for the different format.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php